# How to Override Node Bootstrap styles in Rails 5.1?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5, yarnpkg

When using the "new" Rails 5.1 Paradigm of Yarn & Webpack: If I include bootstrap using Yarn (NOT using a gem) as follows:

```
yarn add jquery
yarn add bootstrap
```

Then with `application.js` of:

```
*= require bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap
```

Everything seems to be working great... Except overriding a bootstrap style.

What is the *proper* way now to override a style that is provided by bootstrap (e.g. a body style that comes from `/bootstrap/less/scaffolding.less`)

Anything put in a .css file in **/app/assets/stylesheets** such as `before_bootstrap.css`:

```
body {
  background-color: #333;
}
```

gets overridden by the style in scaffolding.less, *regardless* of whether you **require** that css file *before* or *after* the `application.css` line:

```
  *= require_tree .
  *= require_self
  *= require before_bootstrap
  *= require bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap
  *= require after_bootstrap
```

The *old* way, I suppose, would have been to use a `bootstrap_and_overrides.css` file and **@import ???** but I don't see how that works with the node/webpack paradigm.

Comment: i'm wondering the same thing, trying to go full webpack instead of mixing it up with sprockets (which just feels wrong) but finding it pretty unclear what the "Best" method is as well.  Any progress?

Comment: Nothing yet.  I'm on to other functionality now but eventually I'll need to come up with something useful for these overrides in 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have this working, here's what I did:

1. Added my sass files (variables, the bootswatch file, and some globals) to the `/app/javascripts` root folder
2. Created an `packs/app` pack folder as my projects base pack

in that pack folder:

3. Created `index.js` where my import statements are
4. Created `styles.scss` where sass import statements are

My styles.scss starts with:

```
@import "../../variables.scss";

$icon-font-path: "~bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";

@import "../../bootswatch.scss";
@import "../../utils.scss";
```

which is working great, loads base bootstrap, followed by the bootswatch, and variables stick.

As the project progresses i'll make new pack folders if necessary for specific functionality, though this is a pretty pure "rails" app, so we'll see as it grows.

Comment: Thanks for the comments but it is still ignoring my variables.  Did you have to do something to get webpack to see the new app/javascript/packs/app folder you created?  Anything special in your index.js import statements?

Comment: I have essentially gotten around this by using more specificity in my css and using an after_bootstrap.css file.  I'll mark MBHNYC's answer as correct because it should work for the original question.

Comment: Thanks, and glad you solved it, sorry i didn't get back to you on the question, i'd moved on to a different project and didn't have a chance to go fiddle with it.